# (Non)Prescription Drug Use Location/Date

Tags: data-request, medical, drugs

I'm doing a data science project that requires information about the use of specific prescription and over-the-counter drugs by location and date. The location data don't have to be US-specific, but should be more fine-grained than "country" if possible.

I looked at the FDA Adverse Events database, but it doesn't seem list anything other than country.

I have also poked around in Google Trends (assuming that search for a particular drug correlates with its usage) and there is some useful data there, but pulling it together seems like it will be a pain.

Does anyone know of data bases that can directly or indirectly provide this information?